# Storybook Angular - Error: cssText is undefined when loading component with LESS style

Tags: angular, webpack, less, storybook, ng-zorro-antd

I'm getting the error above in a project that I have set up in the following manner:

- Angular 16 (`ng new myApp --style less --strict`)
- Added NG-Zorro (`ng add ng-zorro-antd`)
- Added Storybook (`npx storybook init`)
- Set up Storybook with LESS according to the [recipe](https://storybook.js.org/recipes/less) (using addon-styling)
- Set up [Custom Webpack Browser Builder build/serve for NG-Zorro](https://ng.ant.design/docs/customize-theme/en#override-by-customized-style-variables)
- Imported main LESS style file from Angular on `.storybook/preview.ts` (`import '../src/styles.less';` -- this is optional)
- Imported the same webpack configuration as `webpackFinal` in `main.ts` file of Storybook (see `main.ts` excerpt below)
- Added an Angular component with LESS styling.
- Created a Story for that component.

The component renders OK if I use it on the application itself, but when I try to open the component on Storybook I get the error above (`Unhandled Promise rejection: cssText is undefined ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: cssText is undefined`)

I have tried all sorts of things someone could imagine, like not loading NG-Zorro stylesheets in the preview, using absolute paths, relative paths, putting styles only in one file and not calling other LESS files. I'm quite lost on this one. It is almost like the compiled less styles are not being loaded by Storybook. Do you guys have any idea?

Thank you in advance!

---

Storybook `main.ts` file excerpt:

```
    import custom from '../extra-webpack.config.js';
    .
    .
    webpackFinal: async (config) => {
        return {
            ...config,
            module: {
                ...config.module,
                rules: [
                    ...(config.module?.rules ?? []),
                    ...custom.module.rules,
                ],
            },
        };
    },
```

`extra-webpack.config.js` file

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                loader: 'less-loader',
                options: {
                    lessOptions: {
                        javascriptEnabled: true,
                    },
                },
            },
        ],
    },
};
```

Comment: Hey, @cezarlamann , I'm facing the very same issue right now, dod you have any luck solving the problem?

Comment: Hey, @jimmyrap. I didn't manage to solve this issue. However, at the end of the day, you don't need this amount of customization. You can just not do what I did, and it will work.